# Using WindowBuilder Pro the design tab is missing several components

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, windowbuilder

I'm doing a project using WindowBuilder Pro and all has been fine up until now. When I am in the "design" tab the preview of the GUI and the components view do are missing a lot of the components from my code.

Here my interface when compiled: 
[image]
As you can see there are several components

And here is the design tab: 
[image]

All that is shown in the Components section and the Preview section is the Main Tabs component and the components it contains. Just a couple of days ago the components section was fine, it showed all the components that you can see in the first image. What is the problem?

Edit: Just in case anyone's interested, I did some messing around and I have an if-else conditional in my constructor which seems to mess things up - without it everything works ok

Comment: Did you manually change the generated code? UI IDEs can have a hard time parsing code that's been manually changed.  Also, this question probably belongs on a WindowBuilderPro support forum and is marginally valid for SO.

Comment: whenever you add components from code it doesnot show up on design view. Probably thats the issue

Comment: @JimGarrison yeah I did, ok I guess that must be the problem.

Comment: @user2281527 ok, I did add some code manually and it showed up, but I suppose too much manual coding doesn't work.

Comment: Revert the code from your source-control system (you _are_ using source-control, right?) and see if that restores the expected behavior.

Comment: @JimGarrison yup that's exactly what I did, thanks